# Placement of OV/UV OC protection circuits

Tags: protection, tvs

[image]

Should the over voltage protection circuit placed after the TVS diode? What is the general way of placing the protection blocks? Am I missing anything apart from these protection blocks?

Answer (score 1):

No like this, the fastest device should be nearer to the input. In general the OV/OC protection is slower than the TVS so an overvoltage peak at the input will trigger the TVS first and maybe blow the fuse, protecting the (more expensive !) OV/OC circuit.

Comment: According to this[Application Note](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88440/failurem.pdf) FUSE should come before the TVS. 
Althoughh I agree with you about protecting the " more expensive" part, I want to ensure  the safety of the entire circuit

Comment: OK, I was not suggesting to move the fuse anywhere else ! The fuse must where it is in your schematic. The fuse protects against overcurrent which will flow when the TVS triggers. I actually see the TVS and the fuse as ONE protection. Only a TVS by itself is not enough.

Comment: Sorry about that @FakeMoustache . I misinterpreted it

Comment: No worries :-) As long as it is clear to you now.